# Rigidbody Mobs fall through ground while walking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a really odd issue, I created custom MOB AI in unity for my game (it has procedural generated voxel world so agents didn't work well). I use rigidbody on the mobs which I move around.

But I have this issue where mobs go inside the floor while moving (doesn't happen when standing) and when they stand, they teleport back up!. It's not animation, I disabled animations and it still happens.

here is how I move them:

```
   private void WalkToTarget()
{
    if (goal != Vector3.zero)
    {
        if (goal.y <= 5)
        {
            currentstatus = MOBSTATUS.STANDING;
            return;
        }
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(VoxelPlayPlayer.instance.transform.position, gameObject.transform.position);
        if (distance < 15)
        {
            goal = VoxelPlayPlayer.instance.transform.position;
            goal.y = VoxelPlayEnvironment.instance.GetHeight(goal);
        }
        if (distance < 5)
        {
            this.currentstatus = MOBSTATUS.ATTACKING;
        }
        //MOVEMENT HAPPENS HERE
        Vector3 direction = (goal - mobcontroller.transform.position).normalized*2f;
        if(mobcontroller.collisionFlags!=CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow)
        direction+= Vector3.down;
        mobcontroller.Move(direction * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        RotateTowards(direction);
    }
}
```

Edit:

All code: https://pastebin.com/khCmfKGi

Comment: Do you have colliders on your ground?

Comment: @Ruzihm Yeah. It seems like sometimes the if statement is correct while moving which makes it decrease the Y value. The if statement is to check if player is grounded and if not to add gravity, but for some reason sometimes when its grounded and running it also doesnt detect ground, and it happens randomly sometimes it does and sometimes it does not. I also attempted it with normal terrain and same issue

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you are using `CollisionFlags` incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
if(mobcontroller.collisionFlags!=CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow)
```

You need to do this

```
if(mobcontroller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow)
```

Because you are trying to check if the mob is **at least** colliding below, not if the mob is **only** colliding below.

Even then, `CharacterController.Move` should not move you through colliders *on its own*.

I suspect that RotateTowards(direction) might be rotating the boundaries of mob's collider through the ground in some cases. To prevent that, I recommend creating a lookDirection that keeps the character rotation flat when you do your RotateTowards:

```
Vector3 direction = (goal - mobcontroller.transform.position).normalized*2f;
if(mobcontroller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow)
    direction+= Vector3.down;
mobcontroller.Move(direction * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Vector3 lookDirection = (goal - mobController.transform.position);
lookDirection.y = mobController.transform.y;
RotateTowards(lookDirection);
```

Comment: it doesnt let me use && with collissionflags. I however attempted:  if (!((mobcontroller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Below)!=0)) and the issue is still there. I'll edit in all the code, you can see that I don't change the position of the colider anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a typo. I edited my answer and included some more information.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened when using `Rigidbody` and `CharacterController` on the mob. Removing `Rigidbody` from the mob solved this problem.

Comment: Yeah. Weird stuff.